# Add a C# DataTable's data into an existing MSSQL Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I am wondering if there is a way to write a c# DataTable's data into an existing Microsoft SQL database table.

In my code, I have imported an Excel sheet into a DataTable. I would like to add the contents of the DataTable to an existing SQL table. Is there an easy way to do this?

I found this stack question ([How to insert a data table into SQL Server database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075159/how-to-insert-a-data-table-into-sql-server-database-table)) that sort of touches on what I would like to do.

Or do I need to run the DataTable through a loop and insert each row of data through code?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075159/how-to-insert-a-data-table-into-sql-server-database-table, which is identical to this question.

Comment: PocketDews: You are right. I looked at the code wrong. That is exactly what I need to do.