# SQL Insert with value from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert, insert-into

I have 2 tables storing information. For example:
Table 1 contains persons:

```
ID         NAME         CITY

1          BOB          1
2          JANE         1
3          FRED         2
```

The CITY is a id to a different table:

```
ID         NAME

1          Amsterdam
2          London
```

The problem is that i want to insert data that i receive in the format:

```
ID         NAME         CITY

1          PETER        Amsterdam
2          KEES         London
3          FRED         London
```

Given that the list of Cities is complete (i never receive a city that is not in my list) how can i insert the (new/received from outside)persons into the table with the right ID for the city?

Should i replace them before I try to insert them, or is there a performance friendly (i might have to insert thousands of lines at one) way to make the SQL do this for me?

The SQL server i'm using is Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: How are you receiving the data?

Comment: Where did Bob go, and who's Kees?

Comment: @jarlh: That is the data to be inserted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff im receiving this data from a external application ;)

Comment: And how do you put it in your SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, load the data to be inserted into a table.

Then, you can just use a `join`:

```
insert into persons(id, name, city)
     select st.id, st.name, c.d
     from #StagingTable st left join
          cities c
          on st.city = c.name;
```

Note:  The `persons.id` should probably be an identity column so it wouldn't be necessary to insert it.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into persons (ID,NAME,CITY) //you dont need to include ID if it is auto increment
values 
(1,'BOB',(select Name from city where ID=1)) //another select query is getting Name from city table
```

if you want to add 1000 rows at a time that'd be great if you use stored procedure like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9075853/5292650)

Comment: if i insert a thousand a records at a time, wont it result in the sub-query running a thousand times?

Comment: that'd be great if you write stored procedure for that it is way efficient thn inline query

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.