# Passing a Data table to stored procedure - C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am constructing a data table and passing it as a parameter to the stored procedure. After execution, the stored procedure will provide a result set.

@RefData is the Table parameter name.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tvpKeyValue] AS TABLE(
    [KeyID] [bigint] NULL,
    [KeyValue] [bigint] NULL,
    [KeyValueText] [varchar](500) NULL
)
```

```cs
//Data table
DataTable InputRefTable = new DataTable();

//Adding columns
DataColumn col = null;
col = new DataColumn("KeyID", typeof(Int32));
InputRefTable.Columns.Add(col);
col = new DataColumn("KeyValue", typeof(Int64));
InputRefTable.Columns.Add(col);
col = new DataColumn("KeyValueText", typeof(String));
InputRefTable.Columns.Add(col);

//Adding row values
DataRow workRow;
foreach (var item in referenceListInfo)
{
    string genName = string.Empty;
    var refHeadingXid = context.ViewBookingReferenceDescription.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyID == companyId && c.Description == item.name)?.ReferenceHeadingID;
    if (refHeadingXid != null)
    {
        workRow = InputRefTable.NewRow();
        workRow[0] = Convert.ToInt64(refHeadingXid);
        workRow[1] = Convert.ToInt64(refHeadingXid);
        workRow[2] = item.value;
        InputRefTable.Rows.Add(workRow);
    }
}

//Parameters
var param = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", companyId),
    new SqlParameter ("@RefData",InputRefTable)
};

param[1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param[1].TypeName = "dbo.tvpKeyValue";
var rawSql = "EXECUTE usp_triprequest_GET_DynamicRefData @CompanyID, @RefData";
var a = context.ReferenceTableOutput.FromSql(rawSql, param).ToList();
```

Earlier I got the following exception when I did not provide Typename

> The table type parameter '@RefData' must have a valid type name

Then added line param[1].TypeName = "dbo.tvpKeyValue";
Getting exception

> "Operand type clash: tvpKeyValue is incompatible with bigint"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.ArgumentException: The table type parameter must have a valid type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817997/system-argumentexception-the-table-type-parameter-must-have-a-valid-type-name)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46539409/3270427) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/passing-datatable-to-storeprocedure-as-parameter-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Try adding a table name to the constructor : DataTable InputRefTable = new DataTable("Table Name")

Comment: @jdweng what should be the table name? Which table exactly is this about

Comment: The table name should be the type of `@RefData`. This should be a table-valued parameter of a particular table type. This is part of the declaration of the stored procedure.

Comment: The issue is with c# not the database.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have done some changes to code. Please review once

Comment: Your procedure doesn't actually take a table as its input, so what you're doing cannot work. Either change the sproc to take a table-valued parameter, or change your code to invoke the stored procedure once per row you have (which is obviously more cumbersome, and slower) or else write a new view, table-valued function or query to retrieve all the data at once.