# How make Insert Into table SQL from DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, dataset

I have json which the converted to Dataset. And this data I wanna written to table in SQl. But I don't know how this doing. I did tried doing through SqlBulkCopy but me this  don't likes because that needed create other table. And data always different.Thanks.

Comment: try going to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075159/how-to-insert-a-data-table-into-sql-server-database-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075159/how-to-insert-a-data-table-into-sql-server-database-table)

Comment: Another option is passing the JSON directly to SQL and using a procedure you parse the data into desired tables.

Comment: I've work with mssql 2008 and there it seems musn't work with json