# Multiply rows of a

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a database table that looks like this:

| ItemCode | Price |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 12.50 |
| DEF | 9.99 |

Then let's say I have a separate GUI where I am trying to run a query that finds the sum of all rows on my dynamic GUI against it's quantity*price from the database.

| ItemCode | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 5 |
| DEF | 8 |

So for the above table, the result of my select query would be 142.42. The confusion I have is that the GUI table I am making can have any Quantity inputted, so where do I feed the Quantity into the query. I thought about running a select query per line and using C# to multiply the results but that seems like a unnecessary load of queries to run each time.

Comment: i would use a view for sake of performance returning the calculation.

Comment: By "GUI table" do you mean you're using some kind of `DataGrid` or `DataGridView`? If so, why use SQL at all?

Comment: So the prices are in the database and the amounts in your app? Then just select the prices from the database and do the calculation in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pass your GUI table as a parameter, you would put your data into a DataTable in C# and create a table-valued parameter in SQL Server with the same structure.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075159/how-to-insert-a-data-table-into-sql-server-database-table) for more details

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Assuming your two tables are t1 & t2:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(t1.Price * t2.Quantity), 2) AS Sum
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode;
```

| Sum |
| --- |
| 142.42 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8xO39gyU)

Comment: Explicit JOIN is the way to go from now on.    Take a peek at https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/10/08/sql-server-why-should-you-not-to-use-old-style-join/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I only did the old way because I thought it was faster but I found out that they both are the same or close performance wise so the explicit join would be much better for readability and catching errors.